# Unhandled exception at project in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, unhandled-exception

I am trying to compile a opencv project from visual studio 2010. I ve already created in vs2008, but I want to it compile it also from vs2010. I put all dependecies and includes, however during the running process I am receiving the following message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7c812fd3 in myProject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0011fa60..
```

My source code its just an imread function. So it has to be something from the installation process in opencv in vs2010.

In debug I am receiving in modules: opencv_highgui246.dll cannont fild or open the PDB file.
 EDIT:

My code:

```
    try{
Mat A;
Mat D (A, Rect(10, 10, 100, 100) ); 
imshow( "Display window", D );  
waitKey(0);
}

catch (cv::Exception& e) {
cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

And what I am receiving

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.widt
h <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in
unknown function, file .\src\matrix.cpp, line 323
.\src\matrix.cpp:323: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.
width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows
```

EDIT2:

I ve change the code:

```
    try{
Mat image = imread("8516.jpg", 1);
imshow( "Display window", image );  
waitKey(0);
}

catch (cv::Exception& e) {
cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Now I am just receiving the unhandled error.

Comment: Did you include vc10 libs/bin instead of vc9 ? just a cross check, though, it might not has anything to do with the exception.

Comment: Should you initialize Mat A first? Like `Mat A(Size(320,240),CV_8UC3);` before because ROI (region of interest) seems to be out of bounds.

Comment: Mabe you are right about that, but its not the case. I ve tried also to initialize A with imread an image and I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the edit, clearly, the problem is with the code,

what do you want to crop from "A", when there is nothing in it, load an image before doing it.

```
Mat A = imread("something.jpg");
Mat D (A, Rect(10, 10, 100, 100) ); 
imshow( "Display window", D );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching that exception?

```
try {
// Your code.
}
catch (cv::Exception& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```